# Need Help in Retrieving Kafka Certificate (.jks file) code from secure place in Java

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to receive my SSL certificate and password from a secure place but not able to understand how to write the code in Kafka configuration to get those certificate and password values.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, the question isn't specific to Kafka. Same question could be asked about API keys or JDBC credentials...

Simplest way, if you trust the runtime environment, would be to define environment variables prior to starting your app, and use `System.getEnv` to retrieve them.

Otherwise, popular options include Hashicorp Vault, or if you're running your code in the cloud, use their own secrets managers

Comment: Thanks for your response.
My requirement is specific for writing Java code to access Certificate (.jks file) from Secure Credentials Vault (SCV) location.
As of now, can not use any other option. Need assistance in writing code to retrieve the certificate from SCV.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement is specific for writing Java code to access Certificate (.jks file) from Secure Credentials Vault (SCV) location.
As of now, can not use any other option. Need assistance in writing code to retrieve the certificate from SCV.